# POCOs aren't updating?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

I have a problem with the Entity Framework. 
When I update the model from the database, it shows in the diagram the new property that I created in a table but it doesn't update the Entity Classes.

The model's configuration has the `Code Generation Strategy` property and this is disabled, but if I change the value of the property to "Default" (not sure if in English is said so, in spanish is "Predeterminado"), it duplicates all classes that I created before.

I don't know what to do to fix this problem, I have searched and have not found solutions

I appreciate any help you can give me

Comment: Have you also selected Validate after you updated the model?

Answer (score 0):

ASAIK, when the code generation is disabled, you are in charge of the updates the POCO classes . You need to either update the POCO classes yourself to remove your POCO classes and let the entity framework handle the class generation for you.

I recommend manual updates, as it gives you great flexibility and will allow you to move to [n-tired model](http://blog.jorgef.net/2010/09/n-tiers-pocos-ef-1.html).

Answer (score -1):

Frequently inside the same directory as an EF diagram file there is a .tt file.

Try right clicking on that .tt file and clicking on "Run Custom Tool".

Comment: Clarifying questions should be posted as comments.  If you're proposing this as the answer then you shouldn't frame it in the form of a question.

Comment: @Servy that's complete BS. If i had dropped the question mark and and rewrote the last part "Try right clicking on that .tt" then it wouldn't have been a question. But you know what? It would've still contained the same content-- a plausible way to fix his issue. Which = answer.

Comment: @Micah Which is exactly what I'm asking you to do.  I'm not saying, "this shouldn't have been posted," I was asking you to rephrase your answer so that it was in the form of an answer, rather than in the form of a question.

Comment: @Servy But if it has the same content matter why does the punctuation matter? It doesnt. The user isn't going to scour my attempted answer searching for the punctuation, he's going to look for the content that leads to the solution. Come on.

Comment: @Micah One can make the same argument for poor spelling, capitalization, formatting, grammar, etc.  It doesn't make the answer wrong, but getting it right still makes it easier to process.  It also makes the answer look, at first glance, to be a request for clarification, even though it's not.  You should feel confident enough in your answer to make it *an answer*.  As I said, I'm not saying the answer should be deleted, I'm just asking you to edit it to improve it to fix this one issue with it.  That it's good enough to not be deleted doesn't mean it can't be improved.

Comment: @Servy That sort of counter argument = slippery slope fallacy. Fixing it regardless, time to move on